# Enums and Functions

Tags: c++, function, enums

I have this enum declaration in my `CDrawView` class:

```
enum shape{line, rect, elli};
```

In my other class called Shapemaker I have a function which is supposed to take in the enums from the `CDrawView` class and evaluate them

```
  Shape* Shapemaker::shapeCreate(CDrawView::shape)
 {
  if(CDrawView::shape.line == 0)
    return new Line();

  else if(CDrawView::shape.rect == 1)
    return new Rect();

  else if (CDrawView::shape.ellip == 2)
    return new Ellip();
 }
```

I call the function by doing `Shapemaker::shapeCreate(current_shape)` where `current_shape` is just an instance of the `enum shape`.

```
  shape current_shape;
```

This gives me compile errors:

```
error C2653: 'CDrawView' : is not a class or namespace name
Shapemaker.h(7):
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right way to use enums and functions or even compare the enums.

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'shape'
'Shapemaker::shapeCreate' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

#### CDrawView.h

```
class CDrawView : public CScrollWindowImpl<CDrawView>
{
  public:

   CDrawView();
   enum shape{line, rect, elli};
       shape current_shape;
       //...
};
```

The file defining `Shapemaker::shapeCreate()` does `#include "CDrawView.h"` at the top.

Comment: We'll have to see `CDrawView` if it's complaining about it not being a class.

Comment: The `.ellip` is a typo for `.elli`.  But you haven't got to that error yet.

Comment: "enums from the CDrawView class" - is the file defining `Shapemaker::shapeCreate` including the header for `CDrawView`?  If `CDrawView` is in a namespace, you will need to prepend it ala `Shape* Shapemaker::shapeCreate(namespace1::[namespace2::...::]CDrawView::shape)` etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  As you can tell from the comments to the question and the answer, the difficulty is that you've not provided enough information in the question to let us explain the problem to you.  You need to show the larger context in which the `enum shape` is declared.  We don't need masses more code, but we do need enough more code.  Please read about how to provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CDrawView::line` instead of `CDrawView::shape.line`.

The `CDrawView::shape` is to be used only where you need a type - for eg for declaring a variable.

```
A::shape var = A::line;
```

Also the below code is meaningless

```
Shape* Shapemaker::shapeCreate(CDrawView::shape)
{
    if(CDrawView::shape.line == 0)
        return new Line();

    else if(CDrawView::shape.rect == 1)
        return new Rect();

    else if (CDrawView::shape.ellip == 2)
        return new Ellip();
}
```

Change it to

```
Shape* Shapemaker::shapeCreate(CDrawView::shape s)
{
    if(s == CDrawView::line)
        return new Line();

    else if(s == CDrawView::rect)
        return new Rect();

    else if (s == CDrawView::ellip)
        return new Ellip();
}
```

Or even better change it to use `switch case`.

The original code has many problems

1. You don't have a variable name for the function parameter - I have changed it to give the variable a name `s`.
2. `CDrawView::line` is a constant - it's always going to be 0. So it will always return `true`. Your function will always return `new Line()`.
3. The other `if`s are also comparing 2 constants and will also return `true` if they were were ever reached - which they won't be.

Comment: thank you so much..you've been the only person who was able to answer me

Comment: @user2221404 I have updated the answer with few more things now.